# hide files list in Kendo upload component

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I use the Kendo Upload component for Angular 2.

I cannot figure out how to hide the file list below the uploader button. I know it can be customized using ng-template  but I want it to be hidden. I've tried setting the class like this :

```
.k-upload-files{
    display: none;
}
```

but this has no effect.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file-list can be hidden by utilizing the `showFileList` input. [API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#toc-showfilelist)

```
<kendo-upload
    [showFileList]="false"
    ...
>
</kendo-upload>
```

Alternatively you can use a css rules to hide the file-list (as you already stated in your question).

```
.k-upload-files {
    display: none;
}
```

I've prepared an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jFxzq8u12nnPhbfnANSo?p=preview) showing both approaches in action.

Comment: thank you. Somehow I did not see this showFileList parameter in the API...